# Newbie regular expressions questions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to add to my range the `/` character. I tried escaping with `\` but to no avail. My goal is to strip an input field of any characters not allowed in mod_rewrite URL. Leaving just alpha-numeric, `-`, `_` and `/`.

Here is the reg-exp which returns all characters NOT matching a-z, 0-9, A-Z, _ and -

```
/[^a-z0-9_-]/gi
```

I tried:

```
/[^a-z0-9_-\/]/gi
```

And the relevant code block:

```
$('#meta_pageurl').bind('input', function() {
    var c = this.selectionStart,
    r = /[^a-z0-9_-]/gi,
    v = $(this).val();
    if(r.test(v)) {
        $(this).val(v.replace(r, ''));
        c--;
    }
    this.setSelectionRange(c, c);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
r = /[^\w\/-]+/g
```

- `\w` represents `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- hyphen should be at first or last position to avoid escaping
- `/` needs to be escaped
- `+` is used for efficiency (means 1 or more matches)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! +1 can accept in 10 mins

Comment: Though from my experience I can tell you that `mod_rewrite` allows pretty much any character including space.

Comment: My biggest problem was with my client trying to use `$` dollar sign. The space is not a `mod_rewrite` issue, but a convention of my own. I want them to use `-` or `_` instead because URLs in emails and other services that get auto-linked, often break after the space.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
/[^a-z0-9_\/-]/gi
```

Always place `-` at the end of the character class if you want to specify it without escaping. Otherwise, `-` will be interpreted as part of character range syntax, e.g. `a-z`

Answer (score 0):

use `\-` instead of `-`

otherwise it is considered as `_-\/` which means any character from `_` to `/`